# HttpClient 4 silently hangs on socketRead

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, httpclient

I have an application that continuously polls a remote HTTP API using a keep-alive connection.

Rarely but occasionally the application will hang silently after working for a while.
The socket is still open, but the remote API returns no data.

Httpclient has socket timeouts and connect timeouts, but how do I handle a timeout where we are already connected, the socket is still open but the server returns no data?

`netstat -np` for process:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 redactedlocalip:31136       redactedforeignip:80        ESTABLISHED 11145/java
```

My httpclient:

```
SocketConfig socketConfig = SocketConfig.copy(SocketConfig.DEFAULT).setSoTimeout(25000).build();
BasicHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setSocketConfig(socketConfig);
return HttpClients
        .custom()
        .setUserAgent(USER_AGENT)
        .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
        .setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler())
        .build();
```

Main thread dump:

```
"main" #11 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f6b802ce800 nid=0x2b9f runnable [0x00007f6b675ec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:139)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:155)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:284)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261)
        at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:165)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:271)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at redacted.app.code.executemyRequest(MyClass.java:117)
```

Im using the latest version from maven "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5"

Comment: The read timeout should expire and a `SocketTimeoutException` should be thrown. Are you sure this isn't happening? You have 25 seconds of blocking before it happens.

Comment: It hangs forever, well hours at least. No SocketTimeoutException occurs.
There must be some sort of keepalive from the server, but I don't have wire logs.

Comment: Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was a poorly behaving HTTP server that never responded to certain requests yet continued to maintain the TCP connection and send/receive keep-alive packets.
Apache HTTPClient does not have any built in timeout to deal with these scenarios, the solution is to call the HTTPRequest$abort() method manually after a nominated amount of time waiting.
It of course needs to be called from a different thread as the calling thread will be blocked waiting.